# How to make a wrap for std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I am building a simple class to execute atomic operations, but I got error when I tried call the method `call`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

template<typename _Tp>
class Atom {
  _Tp val_;
  std::mutex mtx_;

public:
  Atom() = default;
  ~Atom() = default;
  Atom(const Atom&) = delete;
  Atom& operator=(const Atom&) = delete;
  Atom& operator=(const Atom&) volatile = delete;

 // FIXME:
 template<typename Ret, typename... _Args>
  Ret call(_Tp&& f, _Args&&... args) {
    mtx_.lock();

    auto b_fn = std::bind(static_cast<Ret(_Tp::*)(_Args...)>(f), 
                std::ref(val_), std::forward<_Args>(args)...);

    Ret r = b_fn();
    mtx_.unlock();
    return r;
  }

  operator _Tp() {
    return load();
  }

  _Tp operator= (_Tp val) {
    store(val);
    return val;
  }

  _Tp load() {
    _Tp tmp;
    mtx_.lock();
    tmp = val_;
    mtx_.unlock();
    return tmp;
  }

  void store(_Tp val) {
    mtx_.lock();
    val_ = val;
    mtx_.unlock();
  }
};
```

I try to use like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Atom<std::string> str;
  str = "asdf";
  // FIXME:
  str.call(&std::string::append, std::string("test"));

  std::string ot = str;
  std::cout << ot << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Atom<std::basic_string<char> >::call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::string)’
       str.call(&std::string::append, std::string("test"));
```

Comment: Names beginning with `__` or `_X` where X is a capital letter are reserved names for implementation in every namespace.  Names beginning with `_` are reserved in the gloabal namespace.  Using them is UB.  You should avoid it.

Comment: OmnipotentEntity, you are right, in the real application it will be in a namespace, it's only an example to use here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Alex, I think you misread, names containing `__` or beginning with `_X` where X is a capital letter are reserved names for implementation in **every namespace.**  It doesn't matter if you put them in a namespace.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, namespace exists to avoid name conflict, if you avoid `using namespace`, so, it is ok!

Comment: Alex, I'm saying that these names are always reserved for implementation, no matter what namespace you put them in.  You could place them in an anonymous namespace and it would still be UB.  Chances are you'd be OK, but you should avoid it anyway.

Comment: This is the best I could come up with :l http://ideone.com/bXtXDc

Comment: @Brandon, it was a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't so much about who to wrap `std::bind()` than about how to take the address of an overloaded [member] function! ... because you'll have exactly the same problem when you try to use `std::bind()`.

There are actually a issues with what you are trying to do:

1. You try to take the address of an overloaded [member] function. The compiler will allow that if the address is immediately used with something determining the exact type, e.g., by passing it to a function taking an appropriate [member] function pointer or by casting it. If it weren't for the second problem, you could use something like this:

   ```
   static_cast<std::string& (std::string::*)(std::string)>(&std::String::append)
   ```

   The cast would deduce which overload is being used.
2. The standard gives explicit permission to the standard library to implement any of the non-`virtual` member function of the classes and class templates to take arbitrary defaulted additional arguments. However, when taking the address of one of these, you'll need to know the exact parameters to get the [member] function pointer matched.

Thus, attempting to `std::bind()` one of the members of classes in the standard C++ library is both rather verbose and also non-portable. The simplest approach is probably to just use a lambda function:

```
std::string test("test")
str.call([=](std::string& s){ return s.append(test); });
```

(obviously, for appending a string literal you wouldn't need an extra variable but I wanted to provide an example with a non-empty closure). Another approach is to create a suitable function object and passed that instead of trying to a pointer to a member function:

```
struct append {
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(std::string& s, Args&&.. args) const
      -> decltype(s.append(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return s.append(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

str.call(append(), std::string("test));
```

I realize that neither of the approaches is as convenient as you'd probably like them to be but at the moment C++ doesn't have a nice approach to create a function object like the one above. It would be great if we had something but I'm not even aware of a corresponding proposal.

BTW, your `call()` function still won't work because there is nothign there appropriate deduce the return type `Ret`. Also, even if it worked it seems to create function object which will modify the supposed to be protected shared object without synchronziation upon call. You probably just want to apply th passed function object while holding the lock (note, that it is generally a bad idea to apply unknown code while holding a lock as it opens up chances to create a dead-lock when the called code comes back and tries to access the object through a diferent route).

Comment: In fact std::string was an example, but my class has to work for any kind of object or method, so I would to like a completely generic wrap for std::bind.